# List all subsites, libraries and folders in site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to run a report for my client that will list the whole site structure in a site collection - subsites, libraries and folders + sub folders - no need to list the files/document inside, I only need the structure.  How can I get something like that?  I use Sharepoint 2016 on premises

Comment: you can get it with poweshell. did you try searching around little bit about this matter? You can find dozens of examples, even whole code scripts that you can use.

Comment: Hi Danilo, I've searched for scripts but it shows file entries, so if there is no file in the library / folder, it does not get listed in the report

Comment: some examples, you will have to combine scripts to get result what you need: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166945/powershell-script-that-outputs-all-folders-from-a-site-collection-site-and-subs or this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b4dfb645-69f4-4abd-947c-64ca42af3a26/script-to-get-list-of-sites-and-subsites?forum=sharepointadminprevious and this one https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/503/powershell-script-to-list-out-the-subsites-lists-item-item-version-counts-and.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Function GetSubFolders($Folder)
{ 
   Write-Host "+"$Folder.Name


   #Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
     foreach ($SubFolder in $Folder.SubFolders)
        {
        if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
        {  
          Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
        GetSubFolders($Subfolder)

      }
    }
 }

#Get the Site collection 
$Site= Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint.com" 
       #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
       foreach($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
       {
      Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------"
      Write-Host "Site Name: '$($web.Title)' at $($web.URL)"
    Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------"
      foreach($list in $Web.Lists)
    {
       #Filter Doc Libs, Eliminate Hidden ones
      if(($List.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false) )
               { 
          GetSubFolders($List.RootFolder)
         }
    }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you Max576, the script gave me what I needed. Much appreciated